# Why prepare is so slow with greenplum?

Tags: php, postgresql, pdo, greenplum

i connect a greenplum,i find that pdo is so slow

my test script is like this

```
<?php
$sql="select keyword from r_keyword_hour where domainId = '68955' and date    >= '2017-01-17' and date < '2017-01-18'   limit 10 offset 0";
$start2 = microtime(true);
$con = pg_connect("host=xxx user=xxx dbname=xxx connect_timeout=5 port=xxx password=21fdcebd7156d1b9");
$result2 = pg_query($con,$sql);
$test=pg_fetch_all($result2);
$end2 = microtime(true);
$start = microtime(true);
$d=new PDO('pgsql:host=xxx user=xxx dbname=xxx connect_timeout=5 port=xxx password=xxx');
$result=$d->query($sql);
$end = microtime(true);
#var_dump($end-$start);
#var_dump($end2-$start2);
echo strval($end-$start)."\t".strval($end2-$start2)."\n"
?>
```

the result is pdo use 1.8s however pg_* just use 0.7s. when the greenplum is overload,pdo became 53.9s,but pg_* just 5s.why pdo such slow?

update:
normally,the whole pdo query spend 1.6s,and the "$result=$d->query($sql);" spend nearly all of this 1.6s,may about 0.01s different.as for the pg_* querys if i use "$result2 = pg_query($con,$sql)" method it just need about 0.8s,and if i use method as @Stephen Carter suggested,prepare first ,it needs about 1.5s.Sometimes if the gp machine overload,the pdo will take about 26s ,at this time pg_* with prepare need 18s, and the pg_query just need 2s

update2:
I captured the packet of pdo request,find that "$result=$d->query($sql)" also use prepare of postgresql.I am not sure is there a way for PDO don't use prepare.But now, we can know prepare will slow down greenplum, I will keep trying to find why.

Comment: Can you profile your code a bit, measuring which part takes which time to execute?

Comment: "$result=$d->query($sql);"this method take most time

Comment: How many "most" in numbers? Can't you be a little bit more certain? It makes an impression that you don't need the answer, and we are forcing you to solve your problem.

Comment: sorry,because my greenplum is not so stable.so i still watching it.till now,normally,the whole pdo query spend 1.6s,and the "$result=$d->query($sql);" spend nearly all of this 1.6s,may about 0.01s different.as for the pg_* querys if i use "$result2 = pg_query($con,$sql)" method it just need about 0.8s,and if i use method as @Stephen Carter suggested,prepare first ,it needs about 1.5s.Sometimes if the gp machine overload,the pdo will take about 26s ,at this time pg_* with prepare need 18s, and the pg_query just need 2s.I really appreciate for your reply

Comment: Add that to your question

Answer (score 2):

You are not comparing like for like.

pg_query is executing a simple query.

PDO is preparing a statement and then executing it.

If you do a prepared statement with pg_* function the execution time should be similar, at least it was when I tested.

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE id > 500";

$con = pg_connect("**********");
$pre = pg_prepare($con, "my_query", $sql);
$exe = pg_execute($con, "my_query", array());
$result=pg_fetch_all($exe);

$d=new PDO("**********");
$sth=$d->prepare($sql);
$sth->execute();
$result = $sth->fetchAll();
```

Or you might be able to change the PDO method to avoid doing a prepare statement.

Comment: yes,you are right,after prepare they are similar though pg_* is still a little bit faster. but why when the greenplum machine overload the prepare one become so slow like i said use nearly 50s,but the simple query just use 5s?

Comment: and how to avoid PDO prepare statement,i use $con->query($sql),however,it doesn't improve the speed.

Comment: @Allen what is "similar" in numbers? Does it mean that pg become slower or PDO faster?

Comment: if i use prepare for pg method, it become slow.pg_* with prepare is similiar to pdo whenever use prepare or not.that means normally pdo use 1.6s,pg_* with prepare use 1.5s,and pg_prepare() method itself always use 0.4s execute() use the other time.someties may the pg_* with prepare will slow than pdo ,but it not happend usually.When greenplum overload. pg_* without prepare also become slow , but just uder 10s.At this time pdo and pg_* with prepare use 20s or more,however,pg_prepare($sql) method itself just spend 0.4s still.

Comment: on my test i use $d->query($sql) for pdo, didn't test pdo prepare any more .